# regex to match tags data from multiple similar tags

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the cxml from the below mentioned XML(can be valid or invalid) which contain multiple cxml tags. I want top most cxml along with its child cxml tags but result I am getting is not as expected.
Regex:

```
public static String selectCxmlFromXml(String xml) {
    String cxml = "";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(<cXML.*</cXML>).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        cxml = matcher.group(1);
    }
    return cxml;
}
```

The input XML(which is not a valid XML):

```
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.037/cXML.dtd">1532298890669-3937185683464996079@216.109.111.68
<cXML payloadID="1532333614215-4720337288049634328@216.109.111.11" timestamp="2018-07-23T01:13:34-07:00">
   <Response>
      <Status code="200" text="OK"/>
      <GetPendingResponse>
         <cXML
            payloadID="1532333614208-7005041222787302474@216.109.111.11" timestamp="2018-07-23T01:13:34-07:00">
            <Message>
               <DataAvailableMessage>
                  <InternalID domain="PendingMessages">140000000000000000010977255</InternalID>
               </DataAvailableMessage>
            </Message>
         </cXML>
      </GetPendingResponse>
   </Response>
</cXML>
```

expected response:

```
<cXML payloadID="1532333614215-4720337288049634328@216.109.111.11" timestamp="2018-07-23T01:13:34-07:00">
   <Response>
      <Status code="200" text="OK"/>
      <GetPendingResponse>
         <cXML
            payloadID="1532333614208-7005041222787302474@216.109.111.11" timestamp="2018-07-23T01:13:34-07:00">
            <Message>
               <DataAvailableMessage>
                  <InternalID domain="PendingMessages">140000000000000000010977255</InternalID>
               </DataAvailableMessage>
            </Message>
         </cXML>
      </GetPendingResponse>
   </Response>
</cXML>
```

response got(incorrect):

```
<cXML payloadID="1532333614208-7005041222787302474@216.109.111.11" timestamp="2018-07-23T01:13:34-07:00">
            <Message>
               <DataAvailableMessage>
                  <InternalID domain="PendingMessages">140000000000000000010977255</InternalID>
               </DataAvailableMessage>
            </Message>
         </cXML>
      </GetPendingResponse>
   </Response>
</cXML>
```

notice that the first cxml declaration and its data got skipped.
If I use `.*(<cXML.*?</cXML>).*`, then only the internal cxml got selected and the external cxml get skipped.

```
<cXML payloadID="1532333614208-7005041222787302474@216.109.111.11" timestamp="2018-07-23T01:13:34-07:00">
   <Message>
        <DataAvailableMessage>
           <InternalID domain="PendingMessages">140000000000000000010977255</InternalID>
        </DataAvailableMessage>
     </Message>
</cXML>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong here?*. You're using regex. Use an XML parser to make your life 1000 times easier

Comment: Actually the input xml I posted is a valid XML. In real example, the XML could contains some characters in-between the Doctype declaration and the cxml tag. The input xml could be a valid or invalid XML.I am updating the question.

Comment: That should not make a difference. You should still use a parser. If it complains that the XML is invalid, then it is not your job to make it valid.

Comment: Yes, parser complaints about invalid XML. And this is the requirement, to parse the CXML from the XML(could be valid or invalid).

Comment: You are applying regex pattern matching to hierarchical pattern matching. That's the wrong tool for the job (though many regex engines have features to handle recursive patterns. Specifying these patterns grows nasty quickly - only do that if you are not the one to maintain the code _and_ you hate those who are ...;) ). Better use a simple xml parser, they abound for Java and other environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. two things:
1. Use find() instead of match()
2. change regex to `(<cXML.*</cXML>)` which will capture the entire cXML

New method would be:

```
public static String selectCxmlFromXml(String xml) {
    String cxml = "";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<cXML.*</cXML>)", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        cxml = matcher.group(1);
    }
    return cxml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some fiddling I came accross this regex:

```
(<cXML>|<cXML.+>(?:\s|.)*<\/cXML>)
```

To explain what it actually does:

1. `<cXML>|<cXML.+>` matches the opening tag. Which can contain attributes, or not.
2. `(?:\s|.)*` is a *not-capturing-group* which allows every combination of whitespace (`\s`) and other letters (`.`) to be matched.
3. `<\/cXML>` matches the closing tag.

---

## [Working demo](https://ideone.com/mRlUiq)

Comment: No need to put not-capturing-group. We can tell our Regex engine that a dot(.) will match any character including white spaces , new line and any other character. `Pattern.compile("(<cXML.*</cXML>)", Pattern.DOTALL)`
BTW, my code was correct, I just need to use find() instead of match()

Answer (score 0):

No-one should send an invalid XML when you supposedly have accepted -to follow, stick to, adhere to- a standard, protocol, RFC, etc. 
Noting that unstructured data can be sent in a CDATA section.

Yet having said that, if for a good reason you have to deal with invalid XML, how invalid would be? Would be invalid in a predictible way? Let us know. Because using lazy/greedy regex will work -or not- depending on the length of content and the regex processor.

To answer your question, if you are interested in top cXML. I would simply  substring from first occurrence of `<cXML` from the begining of the **String** to the first ocurrence of `</cXML>` from the end (backwards) of the string. Do you expect self-closing tags `/>`?

Answer (score 0):

This question has already good answers but I want to share this website:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

It really helps when writing regular expressions in Java.
I use it every time I need to write some weird regexp.

Hope this helps.